# SQL query for cumulative sum or subtract

Tags: mysql, sql

how to create columns from unique values of a column and do a cumulative addition or subtraction.

I have a record of transactions like this

| transaction_id | created_at | transaction_type | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 124 | 2020-08-06 17:00:09 | 2 | 25.00 |
| 123 | 2020-08-06 17:00:03 | 1 | 50.00 |

There are various types of transactions, which in turn have different effects .Some results are withdrawals from th account, some are deposits and others don’t affect it at all. This information is summarized in another table (let’s call it ‘transaction_types’), as shown below:

| id | description | effect |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Manual Deposit | add |
| 2 | Direct Payment | subtract |

**id in the table transaction_type is a foreign key transactions. transaction_type = transactions_type.id**

now if the initial amount is $10000 I need to create a table like this

| transaction_id | initial_balance | deposit | withdrawal | final_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 100000 | 50 |  | 100050 |
| 124 | 100050 |  | 25 | 100025 |

I don't know how to create new columns based on unique values in some columns also to start a cumulative sum from 10000. This is the query I tried select f.transaction_id, t.created_at, sum(case when d.effect = 'subtract' then -1 else 1 end * amount) from f inner join d on f.transaction_type = d.id

Comment: Ok, and what's stopping you? Show is the query you have and the specific problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: no alghoritm can know that transaction 123 and 124 belong together

Comment: @Stu I don't know how to create new columns based on unique values in some columns also to start a cumulative sum from  10000. This is the query I tried

select f.transaction_id, t.created_at, sum(case when d.effect = 'subtract' then -1 else 1 end * amount)
from f inner join d on f.transaction_type = d.id;

Comment: There must be some additional data you're not sharing - what links those transactions?

Comment: @Stu id in the table transaction_type is a foreign key.  transactions.transaction_type = transactions_type.id

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RECURSIVE RowNums AS
(
    SELECT
        transaction_id,
        created_at,
        CAST(amount AS SIGNED) AS amount,
        effect,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (
            ORDER BY
                created_at, 
                transaction_id
        ) AS RowNum
    FROM transactions t
    JOIN transaction_types tt
    ON t.transaction_type = tt.id 
), 
Balances AS
(
    SELECT
        transaction_id,
        created_at,
        amount,
        effect,
        100000 AS initial_balance,
        100000 +
        (
            CASE effect
                WHEN 'add' THEN amount
                WHEN 'subtract' THEN (-(amount))
            END
        ) AS final_balance,
        RowNum
    FROM RowNums
    WHERE RowNum = 1
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
        rn.transaction_id,
        rn.created_at,
        rn.amount,
        rn.effect,
        b.final_balance,
        b.final_balance +
        (
            CASE rn.effect
                WHEN 'add' THEN rn.amount
                WHEN 'subtract' THEN (-(rn.amount))
            END
        ),
        rn.RowNum
    FROM Balances b
    JOIN RowNums rn
    ON (b.RowNum + 1) = rn.RowNum
)
SELECT
    transaction_id,
    initial_balance,
    CASE effect
        WHEN 'add' 
        THEN CAST(amount AS CHAR(20)) 
        ELSE ''
    END AS deposit,
    CASE effect
        WHEN 'subtract' 
        THEN CAST(amount AS CHAR(20)) 
        ELSE ''
    END AS withdrawal,
    final_balance
FROM Balances
ORDER BY
    created_at,
    transaction_id
```

source : https://www.reddit.com/r/sqltutorial/comments/sx3ycb/comment/hxr6f9l/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3